# Net Core 5 Routing Folder Endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have updated my project to Net Core 5 (from 3.1) using Razor Pages.
I use the standard Razor endpoint routing with folders. Now only routes to subfolders (e.g. "Host.com/Folder1/Folder2/Site") work, but not to simple folders (e.g. "Host.com/Folder1/Site").
CRUD routing also works in subfolders (e.g. "Host.com/Folder1/Folder2/Site/Create").
I only use the default routing in the startup file:

```
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Comment: Hi, did you try to add this code for default routing? `endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`

Comment: Can you share your project folder structure, especially pages folder? Besides, what does "not work" mean? Does it return HTTP 404 error?

Comment: I commented everything out of my startup file and then it worked. It turned out that the prolem was the Localization `services.AddRazorPages().AddExpressLocalization<ExpressLocalizationResource,ViewLocalizationResource>(ops =>...`. Why there is this problem with Net 5 is not clear to me (I have read the Breaking Changes), but the main thing is that it runs for now.